# ggplot2- How to plot continues values in a discrete scale axis values?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have continous value (see cols `log` in data below) that I want to plot in a line char with ggplot2. My code actually do the job But my problem is the values of the y-axis. In fact these values are not well distributed and thus the plot creates wrong visual perception of the scale (see for example the space between the green and the blue lines in the thirth plot of the picture below)

[image]

How can I fix this issue ? Is there a way to force y-axis to organize the countinous values from data around discrete values like (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ?

Here are my data

```
motor;trace;rules;time;log
monetDBIE;1m;R2;1556;3,1
monetDBIE;1m;R1;1590;3,2
monetDBIE;1m;RDFS;15999;4,2
monetDBIE;2m;R2;3319;3,5
monetDBIE;2m;R1;3645;3,5
monetDBIE;2m;RDFS;31239;4,4
monetDBIE;5m;R2;9283;3,9
monetDBIE;5m;R1;10398;4
monetDBIE;5m;RDFS;85806;4,9
Jena;1m;R1;227;2,3
Jena;1m;R2;1203228;6
Jena;1m;RDFS;21;1,3
Jena;2m;R1;321;2,5
Jena;2m;R2;5099199;6,7
Jena;2m;RDFS;21;1,3
Jena;5m;R1;629;2,7
PGSQLIE;1m;R1;8149;3,9
PGSQLIE;1m;R2;6548;3,8
PGSQLIE;1m;RDFS;66116;4,8
PGSQLIE;2m;R1;17029;4,2
PGSQLIE;2m;R2;22523;4,3
PGSQLIE;2m;RDFS;81155;4,9
PGSQLIE;5m;R1;33483;4,5
PGSQLIE;5m;R2;1504944;6,1
PGSQLIE;5m;RDFS;891532;5,9
```

And here is my ggplot2 code

```
require("ggplot2")

w <- read.csv(file="saturation/saturation.csv", head=TRUE, sep=";")

p <- ggplot(data=w, aes(x=trace, y=log, colour=motor, shape=motor))

p <- p + geom_point(size=4)

p <- p + geom_line(size=1,aes(group=motor))

p <- p + geom_text(aes(label=time), hjust=-0.2, vjust=1)

p <- p + ggtitle("Insertion des triplets (R1, R2) et saturation RDFS dans triplestores")

p <- p + scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend(title = NULL))

p <- p + facet_grid(rules~.)

p <- p + theme_bw()

postscript(file = 'saturation.vs.eps')

print (p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *really* want a discrete y scale in this case?  If you change `w$log` to numeric, the graph will format "correctly":

```
# Convert log variable to numeric and substitute commas with decimals
w$log <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", w$log, fixed=TRUE))

ggplot(data=w, aes(x=trace, y=log, colour=motor, shape=motor)) +
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  geom_line(size=1,aes(group=motor)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=time), hjust=-0.2, vjust=1) + 
  ggtitle("Insertion des triplets (R1, R2) et saturation RDFS dans triplestores") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend(title = NULL)) + 
  facet_grid(rules~.) + 
  theme_bw()
```

If you insist on a discrete y scale, you could use `scale_y_discrete(breaks=0:7, labels=0:7)`.

*FYI - you probably want to add `show_guide = FALSE` within `geom_text` to remove the `a` from the legend...that is, `geom_text(aes(label = time), hjust=-0.2, vjust=1, show_guide=FALSE)`*

Comment: (+1) for you answer. the conversion was the good think to do. I did know that a numeric with a coma `,` was consider like a string be `ggplot2`. thanks